# run powershell script from sql server agent (type: powershell)

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am trying to run simple powershell script prom a job(sql server agent).
script:

```
[string]$SrcFolder = "G:\MSSQL\Test";
[string]$TrgFolder = "\\xx.xx.xx.xxx\d$\sql\logshipping" ;

if (-not(Get-Module -Name SQLPS)) 
{
    if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name SQLPS) {
        Push-Location
        Import-Module -Name SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
        Pop-Location
    };
};

if ($SrcFolder -eq $null -or $TrgFolder -eq $null )
    {
        Write-Host "The source Folder = $SrcFolder ,OR target folder =  $TrgFolder is not valid/Null";
    };

$prafix = "[A-Za-z]+_[0-9]+_[0-9].trn" ;
Set-Location -Path C:\ ;
# Copy to Destination
foreach ($file in gci -Path $SrcFolder | Where-Object{ $_.Mode -eq '-a---' -and $_.Extension -eq '.trn' -and $_.Name -match $prafix})
    {
    write-host "Starting Copy File: $($file.FullName) ." ;
        Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $TrgFolder -Force -ErrorAction Stop ;


    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath "$TrgFolder\$($file.Name)")
        {
            write-host "End Copy File: $($file.FullName) ." ;
                Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination "$SrcFolder\Moved" -Force ;
        }
    else
        {
            Write-Host "The Copy File: $TrgFolder\$($file.BaseName) . Failed "

    };
    }
```

The script doing: Copy .bak files to remote server. then check if the bak file exists in the remote server, and if it's exists his move the bak file to a local folder .

The job is failing message:

> Date      9/1/2016 6:29:31 PM Log     Job History (LS_Manual-Copy)
>
> Step ID       3 Server        SQL2012ENT-IR-3 Job Name        LS_Manual-Copy Step
>   Name      Delete Old Logs Duration        00:00:00 Sql Severity   0 Sql Message
>   ID    0 Operator Emailed   Operator Net sent   Operator Paged  Retries
>   Attempted 0
>
> Message Unable to start execution of step 3 (reason: line(23): Syntax
>   error).  The step failed.

the sql server agent is a member in the Administrator group .

please help .

10X

[image]

Comment: I know the question is old. Do you still need help? @itzik Paz

Comment: Does the script runs fine without a SQL Agent job?

Comment: Yes . I run it from ps ise